# curl, отправить файл с cookies на сайт

Tags: curl, cookie, командная-строка

Есть сайт http://... , на него надо отправить запрос с одновременно несколькими куки. Т.к. требуется довольно много куки, я создал файл cookie.txt. 
Пробую следующее:

1. `$ curl -b cookie.txt http://...`
2. `$ curl --cookie cookie.txt http://...`

После чего сайт показывает 0 полученных куки, не зависимо от содержания файла cookie.txt.
Как отправить этот файл, каково должно быть его содержимое?
Чтение мануала не помогло. На данный момент в файле содержится одна обычная кука с обычного сайта. Буду благодарен, если подскажете, как записать в этот файл несколько куки, вида как в следующем примере (который сработал):

```
$ curl -b "1=1"  http://...
```

Версия curl: 7.68.0

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

В документации curl сказано, что

> The file format of the file to read cookies from should be plain HTTP headers (Set-Cookie style) or the Netscape/Mozilla cookie file format.

Где под Set-Cookie style подразумевается формат, используемый в HTTP заголовке Set-Cookie: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Set-Cookie

То есть в файле вам нужно указывать куки в виде:

```
Set-Cookie: name1=value1
Set-Cookie: name2=value2
и т.д.
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не сработало, похоже, это немного не то, т.к. на той же странице написано, что "HTTP заголовок Set-Cookie используется для отправки cookies с сервера на агент пользователя".